# Flutter 'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 26 pos 16: 'url != null': is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to display my user image from Firestore. However showing an error. Showing image with this error.'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 26 pos 16: 'url != null': is not true.

```
class _ChatRoomListTileState extends State<ChatRoomListTile> {
  String profilePicUrl = "",
      name = "",
      username = "";

  getThisUserInfo() async {
    username =
        widget.chatRoomId.replaceAll(widget.myUserName, "").replaceAll("_", "");
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await DatabaseMethods().getUserInfo(username);
    // print("something the data we are getting ${querySnapshot.docs[0].id}");
    name = "${querySnapshot.docs[0]["name"]}";
    profilePicUrl = querySnapshot.docs[0]["imgUrl"];
    setState(() {});
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    getThisUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Showing the image inside in a Row

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child: Image(
              height: 45.0,
              width: 45.0,
              image: NetworkImage(profilePicUrl) == null
                  ? AssetImage('assets/images/emoteU.png')
                  : NetworkImage(profilePicUrl),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `image: NetworkImage(profilePicUrl) == null ? ...` be `image: profilePicUrl == null ? ...` ?

Comment: I tried this. But showing this error `type 'NetworkImage' is not a subtype of type 'String' where
`

Comment: I am facing same error while runing application in the huwai devices.. in other devices application working fine without any error. i am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set your string like this `String profilePicUrl;` Try with this maybe work for you

```
        ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child: profilePicUrl.toString() == null
                ? const Image(
                    height: 45.0,
                    width: 45.0,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/emoteU.png'))
                : Image(
                    height: 45.0,
                    width: 45.0,
                    image: NetworkImage(profilePicUrl),
                  )),
```

Comment: showing this error `'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 26 pos 16: 'url != null': is not true.`

Comment: @AzrafAlMonzim please recheck my answer and if still you are getting same error then your `image URL` is null

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of Image widget

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child:profilePicUrl==null? Image.asset(
              height: 45.0,
              width: 45.0,
            'assets/images/emoteU.png'
          ):
          Image.network(profilePicUrl,
                        height:45,
                        width:45)
```